# How to take the table name to be given in ore.pull() function as a function argument?/

Tags: r

I have a function in R :

```
Wrapper = function(table_name){
  data = ore.pull(table_name)
}
```

But when i'm passing any value it s taken as string than an object name.
how to pass it as a table name?

Comment: any one? or at least an alternative for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered in the below forum.
https://forums.oracle.com/message/11100954#11100954